# Is there a way for GMail Add-ons to hide/disable the Send button

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I'm looking for a way to either make my custom GMail add-on disable the Message send button, or alternatively, send the message without clicking send.

https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable the "Send" button, however, you can send the message they are editing (at the time, a Draft) with the [API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/send) and [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-draft#send).